# How to find a positive semi-definite linear combination?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

Suppose we are given two explicit symmetric matrices $X$ and $Y$ and we'd like to find a non-zero real linear combination $aX+bY$ that is positive semi-definite (if possible).

Is there a way to go about this that is smarter than writing down all principal minors as a functions of a and b and seeing if you can make them simultaneously non-negative?

Comment: In this [link](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~njw/Teaching/Math271C/Lecture_03.pdf) you can find some equivalent characterizations of positive semi-definite. Perhaps you can find some more useful or not.

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned the positive minors criterion because I see how to compute minors as a function of a and b. But I'm not sure how other criteria are easily applicable. Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not know, do your matrices have any specific form, any property? Are they diagonal or full rank or something, or are they random?

Comment: By changing basis, you could always assume that at least one of X and Y is diagonal, but if they were simultaneously diagonalizable, then the problem is trivial. I can also suppose both X and Y are of the form AA^T-Id, where A is some unipotent matrix and fixes a hyperplane. But I'm also interested in more general cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charles Crawford, *[Algorithm 646: PDFIND: a routine to find a positive definite linear combination of two real symmetric matrices](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=214335)*, ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software (TOMS), Volume 12, Issue 3, September 1986. Abstract:

> PDFIND is a FORTRAN-77 implementation of an algorithm that finds a positive definite linear combination of two symmetric matrices, or determines that such a combination does not exist. The algorithm is designed to be independent of the data structures used to store the matrices. The user must provide a subroutine, CHLSKY, which acts as an interface between PDFIND and the matrix data structures. CHLSKY also provides the user control over the number of iterations of the algorithm. Implementations of CHLSKY are included which call LINPAC routines for full matrices as well as symmetric banded matrices.

C.R. Crawford and Y.S. Moon, *[Finding a positive definite linear combination of two Hermitian matrices](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379583901489)*, Linear Algebra and its Applications, Volume 51, June 1983. Abstract:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $n$-by-$n$ Hermitian matrices over the complex field. A result of Au-Yeung [1] and Stewart [8] states that if $x^*(A+iB)x\neq 0$ for all nonzero $n$-vectors $x$, then there is a linear combination of $A$ and $B$ which is positive definite. In this article we present an algorithm which finds such a linear combination in a finite number of steps. We also discuss the implementation of the algorithm in case $A$ and $B$ are real symmetric sparse matrices.

It looks like this second paper is available for free.

Comment: Great. Thank you. I'll take a look at these papers. I am especially looking for something that I can hope to understand with my own two hands, or for which there is user-friendly software. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the algorithm itself doesn't seem to difficult, particularly if you start implementing it in something like MATLAB. Truth is, I didn't know this existed until I decided to search for your question. But I knew it was *likely*. It is well known that the existence of a positive definite linear combination is sufficient to guarantee the existence of a simultaneous diagonalization. So it occurred to me that someone had to have done the work to figure out how to find one.

Comment: Sorry I haven't accepted the answer yet. I was distracted and now need to think it over.